# How to calculate $\sum_{n=1}^\infty {p^{n-1}}{(1-p)^{n}} \frac{1}{n} {2n-2 \choose n-1} $?

Tags: summation

How to prove

$\sum_{n=1}^\infty {p^{n-1}}{(1-p)^{n}} \frac{1}{n} {2n-2 \choose n-1} $

is 1 if $0 \le p \le \frac{1}{2}$

and

smaller than 1 if $\frac{1}{2} \lt p \le 1$?

I came up with this equation while solving another problem, and the only thing I need to do is just solving this equation, but I have no idea..

It seems right when I checked this formula with Wolframalpha.

Can somebody help me proving this equation? Thanks!

Comment: This is direct, using $$\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-4x}}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \binom{2n}{n} x^n,$$ at $x=p(1-p)$.

Comment: @Did But there is additional $ \frac{1}{n} $ term here next to the term ${2n-2 \choose n-1}$. How can I deal with it?

Comment: I am sure you can find a way to compute $$\sum_na_{n-1}\frac{x^n}n$$ starting from $$\sum_na_nx^n.$$

Comment: @Did Oh my god I was stupid thanks!